# Adding Margins to a dynamic Android TextView

Tags: android, textview, margin, android-relativelayout, toast

I've looked through a heap of previous answers on this , and tried the code marked as working, but so far nothing I do can convince the TextView I'm creating at runtme from filling the screen completely from left to right. I want to add a margin on both sides similar to a regular Toast. After that I can add a drop shadow to the shape.

Here my form layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rel_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textColor="@color/holobrightblue"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

.. and my code

```
textView = new TextView(m_Context);
RoundRectShape rs = new RoundRectShape(new float[] { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 }, null, null);

ShapeDrawable sd =  new ShapeDrawable(rs);
sd.setAlpha(m_opacity);
textView.setBackgroundDrawable(sd);             
textView.setTextColor(m_txtcolor);  
textView.setText(toasttitle+"\n"+toastmessage);
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


lp.setMargins(60, 0, 60, 0);          
textView.setLayoutParams(lp);

toastView = new Toast(m_Context);
toastView.setView(textView);
toastView.setDuration(m_toastlen);
toastView.setGravity(m_screengravity, 0,0);
toastView.show();
```

As mentioned, nothing I've tried from other solutions seems to convince the textview from filling all the horizonal space.

I've tried removing that shape etc...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You will **need the holder RelativeLayout which will contain your TextView**,

and then you can set the **holder's Gravity to CENTER**

```
RelativeLayout head2 = new RelativeLayout(this);
head2.setId(++myid);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams head2Params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 25);
head2Params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, head1.getId());
head2.setLayoutParams(head2Params);
head2.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
```

**then your create TextView**

```
textView = new TextView(m_Context);
RoundRectShape rs = new RoundRectShape(new float[] { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 }, null, null);

ShapeDrawable sd =  new ShapeDrawable(rs);
sd.setAlpha(m_opacity);
textView.setBackgroundDrawable(sd);             
textView.setTextColor(m_txtcolor);  
textView.setText(toasttitle+"\n"+toastmessage);
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^MUST  EDIT
lp.setMargins(60, 0, 60, 0);          
textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

**then add your Textview to holder relativeLayout with Center Gravity**

```
head2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
head2.addView(textView);
```

Show it

```
toastView = new Toast(m_Context);
toastView.setView(textView);
toastView.setDuration(m_toastlen);
toastView.setGravity(m_screengravity, 0,0);
```

Comment: Padding will not solve this problem as it will be applied to the TEXT inside of the TextView so that the space between the text and the border will get increased.The person wants the complete TextView to get centered or moved as the given Value from the border of the Screen

Comment: Thanks for taking my comment +vely.Still,the problem will remain as the padding will be applied to the Text that is in the TextView.Are you getting what I am saying??Because the padding is applied to the TextView,it's text will get padded.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that it's the margins I need applied to the textview, which create whitespace between it and the Layout container.

Comment: you can use setBackground(Color.ANY_One) to your textView

Comment: This was very close to being correct. Changing the LinearLayout params to LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT  and then setting the Gravity to textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);  fixed this for me.  The logic to create a Relative layout in code and adding the Textview to it, caused an Exception when the Toast tried to disappear.

Comment: O.K. If you appreciate that my answer was helpful to you, then you can up-vote me and can help me..

Answer (score -1):

This is the easy code to set textview ( text )  to given margins ,

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(text.getWidth(), text.getHeight());
        lp.setMargins(5, 5, 0, 5);
        text.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Parameters of setMargins() are as :

```
LayoutParams.setMargins(int left,int top , int right,int bottom)
```

setLayoutParams take Object of LayoutParams as parameter