# Change background Drawable padding dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I want to Create a View that receives a percentage and displays only this part of background dynamically, as a parameter.

E.g. when creating a view with parameter 0.8; the background is drawn only in 80% of View width (0% padding left, 20% padding right).

I tried to create a DrawableGradient as a View background, but it overlaps whole background and I cannot resize this background.

My next choice was to create InsetDrawable or Layer-List like in this answer: [Android drawable with background and gradient on the left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591836/android-drawable-with-background-and-gradient-on-the-left), but I cannot change the padding dynamically.

The example I use currently:
res/layout/acitvity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/percentage_background_80"
    android:text="80%" 
    android:textSize="16sp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/percentage_background_20"
    android:text="20%"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

drawable/percentage_background_20.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/background"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"/>
    <item
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/view_background"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="200dp"
        android:top="5dp"/>

</layer-list>
```

drawable/percentage_background_80.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/background"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"/>
    <item
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/view_background"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="50dp"
        android:top="5dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

drawable/background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

drawable/view_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item><shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="0"
                android:startColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:endColor="@android:color/white"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
   </item>
</selector>
```

This is how it looks, but I cannot change the values of padding in a list from a source code. Do you know how can I achieve it?

[image: Background with percentage]

Clarification:
in drawable/percentage_background_80.xml and drawable/percentage_background_20.xml there are elements:

```
android:right="XXXdp"
```

I want to change the values XXXdp programatically.

Comment: why dont you use a ClipDrawable ?

Comment: Well, ClipDrawable is almost what I need, but it clips the Drawable from both sides. I couldn't clip it only from the right-hand side.

Comment: use proper Gravity in ClipDrawable constructor

Comment: Oh yeah, you were right. But there is still question, because ClipDrawable removes some part of the background drawable, so GradientDrawable has no use here. Do you know other Drawable, that resizes its child instead of clipping it?

Comment: ScaleDrawable? i suggest some docs reading on Drawable class

Comment: Please, post a comment with both questions, I will mark it as answered and later this day I will send you my edited answer for other people to know.

Comment: not sure what you want me to do :(

Comment: Post a comment with an answer to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either use ClipDrawable or ScaleDrawable depending on wheter you just want to clip target Drawable or resize it

Answer (score -1):

Need add to:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/percentage_background_80"

    android:padding="your_padding"

    android:text="80%" 
    android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

This should works. For dynamically, please read this:

— [how to manually set textview padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478411/how-to-manually-set-textview-padding)

— [Adding Margins to a dynamic Android TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757860/adding-margins-to-a-dynamic-android-textview)

EDIT:

Also, you may add your TextView to layout and change background, like this:

```
<LinearLayout      
  android:id=@"+id/your_id"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/percentage_background_80"
        android:text="80%" 
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in your class just use method **findViewById** and set background.

Comment: This would add padding to the TextView, so the long text won't match the whole width of a TextView. I only want to change the background.

Comment: @Benjamin, what do you mean by 'so the long text won't match the whole width'? You also may use paddingTop, paddingBottom for this purposes.

Comment: i want to create a background like displayed above, not to create padding in a TextView. I want to change background drawable only, without any change in a TextView view itself.
Your proposal changes TextView padding, so the inside would be padded as well.

Comment: Why not use any layout container for TextView and change background drawable only?

Comment: This is the question. How to create a background drawable with dynamically set background parameters...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40705/discussion-between-kvirair-and-benjamin)